# Do male cats mate with dolls or other things, like dogs?

Tags: cats, behavior, breeding

It is well known that lone male dogs "use" (instead of a girl-dog) almost anything else: dolls, furniture, the legs of the people around, and even rabbits and chicken (when available).

However, I have no idea if male cats have a similar inclination. I welcome any information on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite the same nor remotely as common as with dogs, but yes, cats do sometimes hump at random things like inanimate objects.

It's more common with intact males or with males that were neutered later in life, but any cat including females might show the behavior.

However, as I said, it doesn't present quite the same as with dogs. With dogs, it can also be a play or dominance behavior, and so it seems to be much more common for dogs. With cats, if it comes up, it seems to often be a form of self-soothing, as they'll often start doing it as part of kneading on things like blankets, and they might tend to do it more if they're bored or stressed.

Comment: I remember seeing a neutered cat kneading a blanket and humping the air once every 15 or 20 seconds, but I don't know if this fits the question. Was this cat humping? Yes, pretty sure of it. Was he using the blanket or another object? Not sute if it counts. He definitely didn't assume a posture like mating (like dogs do, holding the object with their front legs), he was just standing and kneading and once in a while his hips would... jerk.

Answer (score -2):

The short answer to this is no,this do never happen in cats,male cats and dogs has a very different sexual behaviour,male cats will aggressively seek out the female cat in heat.

I have never seen a male cat finding a replacement mate(object) in the same way as male dogs do when they ride your leg or rub against objects.

Male cats gets exited from the feromones that the females excrete,this is picked up by the vomeronasal organ, Jacobson's organ.

source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vomeronasal_organ

But this does not mean the mating instincts in cats are weaker it only means that a cats brain functions different from many other animals.

None of the feline speicies show the behaviour you describe in your question.

But as you know cats will hunt moving objects and do the bunny kicks but they will not try to mate with them.

You can read more about cats sexual behaviour here:

female cats https://veteriankey.com/female-feline-sexual-behavior/

male cats https://veteriankey.com/male-feline-sexual-behavior/